# How to INDEX from Sheet2 and Sheet3 to find value for Sheet1

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

On Sheet1 I have data based on an Order # and I want the Multiplier that is associated with it. The Multiplier is on both Sheet2 and Sheet3 with the Order #, but the Order #'s and Multipliers associated always change spots in the same column every day so I cannot just copy and paste. I want the Multipler in line with the correct Order # on Sheet1. I attached pictures to help visualize, but the formula I have so far is just for getting Sheet2 Multipliers as I forgot about the 3rd sheet.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

[image: Sheet3]

Comment: Still need to know what you want to do with the two values if the multiplier for a particular order is found in both sheet2 and sheet3.

Comment: Ah I see what what you are saying. If the same value is found in both sheets, the multiplier would be the same either way. So then if there are two, maybe only use one somehow? Maybe using all the multipliers from Sheet2 first and then whatever has not been found, get from Sheet3. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: @user10003190 - you deleted your other question just as I was about to post a solution, so I'm posting this here. Select a range of cells to sort, then click `Data`>`Sort` > `Order`(dropdown)> `Custom List`. See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0S8A.png). Click in the `List Entries` box, type `Bad`, click `Add`, `OK`, `OK`. You now have a custom sort order that will sort "Bad" ahead of numbers as desired. [More Info here]( //support.office.com/article/sort-data-using-a-custom-list-def8ff2b-681a-4fc3-9bd2-a06455c379e1) Next time don't delete so quick; I probably wasn't the only one answering.

Comment: @ashleedawg - I've given up on user10003190. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366753/sort-week-numbers-in-vba-with-changing-data) is another example of a deleted question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about you use a vuplook with iferror. Something like this column D:

= iferror(vuplook(A2;Sheet2!B2:D8;4;true);vuplook(A2;Sheet3!B2:D8;4;true))

That should get the multiplier from sheet two, and if it is not here it should return it from sheet3.

Comment: Good idea but it's giving me a #REF

Comment: Sorry my mistake, should be a 3 and not a 4 for the column index.

Answer (score 0):

Stack the two, passing the lookup to Sheet3 if Sheet2 fails.

```
=iferror(iferror(index(sheet2!d:d, match(a2, sheet2!b:b, 0)), index(sheet3!d:d, match(a2, sheet3!b:b, 0))), text(,))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time